# Setting secret on Azure Keyvault using Managed Identites

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-keyvault

I have an application using Java Springboot and I have already given access from my Managed Identity to the KeyVault.

When I try to set a new secret using the java code I got this error below:

> "message":"Failed to set secret - secret-name \nStatus code 401,
> "{"error":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"AKV10032:
> Invalid issuer. Expected one of

```
public void setAzureTokens() {
    try{
        SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
                .vaultUrl(keyVaultUri)
                .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
                .buildClient();

        secretClient.setSecret(new KeyVaultSecret(key, value));

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        LOG.error("Error during during token update", e);
    }
}
```

Do I need to set any information about Tenant, clientId, or my Managed Identity on Application.properties?

Comment: "Invalid Issuer" usually means that you have multiple tenants/directories in your context and need to select the correct one, e.g. via environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cross-tenant issue as said by @Alex i.e; this  problem arises  for whom has access to multiple Azure AD tenancies and when library for accessing the Key Vault endpoint cannot decide which credentials to authenticate you with.

The solution is to tell the DefaultCredentialProvider which tenancy to use, and can be done with the Options  that you can pass in DefaultAzureCredentialOptions().

```
var o = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions();
o.VisualStudioTenantId = preConfig["AzureTenantId"];
configurationBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(preConfig["KeyVaultName"]), new DefaultAzureCredential(o));
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/714417/unable-to-retrieve-password-from-keyvault-error-ak.html)

(or)

You can set `AZURE_TENANT_ID` as environment variables and can be used as here > [Azure Key Vault Secret client library for Java | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/security-keyvault-secrets-readme?view=azure-java-stable#createget-credentials)

Comment: I realized that I need this ManagedIdentityCredentialBuilder() instead of the Default from Azure. Do I need also these environment variables?

Comment: you may check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-java-stable#credential-classes). AFAIK DefaultAzureCredential and EnvironmentCredential can be configured with environment variables . When it comes to user assigned identity ,we need to provide clientId which can be directly given.